Where to ask for help with identifying a transformer code on a circuit board?
I'm trying to find a site to ask the following question:

I’m working on a project and came across this transformer on a circuit board. I’m trying to find the datasheet or any information about its specifications, but I haven’t had much luck with online searches.
Here are the details from the component:

Code: 380GL52P329H

I've attached a photo of the transformer for reference. It has five pins on one side, and it appears to be labeled with "PRIMARY" on the PCB.
Does anyone recognize this part or know where I might find the datasheet? Any help would be greatly appreciated!




To whoever VTCed this, site-recommendation questions are absolutely on topic here.

@Starship Yep, that was me being an idiot. Apologies. I've had a strong coffee, found my spectacles and won't do it again.

@W.O. It's fine, we all make mistakes sometimes (except for me I am a deity and perfect. I'm talking about the rest of you mortals)

If any SE site, it would be Electrical Engineering.
Check out the Component Identification Question Guidelines.

You're likely to be disappointed though - transformers like that are very often custom-made for a particular customer onto a standard core. So likely that standard core going to the only identifiable part, and you won't know anything about the windings.
